# Inconsistent scale when plotting dates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list of dates formatted with `matplotlib.dates.date2num` and a list of integers. I'm trying to plot a line graph with date on the x-axis. But, matplotlib doesn't always correctly plot the dates when using Python 3. However, I've noticed that this isn't a problem when using Python 2.

This is my code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title(constants.chart_title)
plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-Axis ')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot_date(;ist_of_formatted_dates, list_of_integers)
plt.savefig('chart.png')
```

And here's an example of what the same script outputs using 2 different versions of python:

#### ✅ [Python 2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWc6b.jpg)

#### ❌ [Python 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTtqp.jpg)

When using Python 3, it seems as though matplotlib is plotting all odd-numbered days, and the problem is that March has 31 days so 03-31 and 04-01 are 1 day apart even though all the other odd-numbered days are 2 days apart.

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: This was a deliberate change in 3.0.  However, the intervals used, as you note, are suboptimal, which will be fixed in 3.1.  Please see: https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#changed-default-autodatelocator-kwarg-interval-multiples-to-true  To fix: `locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(interval_multiples=False, )
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locator)`

Comment: @JodyKlymak The spacing is fixed, but I can't figure out how to make chart format dates appropriately. `locator = mpd.AutoDateLocator(interval_multiples=False)` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)` makes it so every tick on the x-axis says 2019. I tried `formatter = mpd.AutoDateFormatter(locator)` and `formatter.scaled[1/(24.*60.)] = '%D'` but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I would appreciate if you could further guide me in the right direction

Comment: You need to set the axis’ formatter.  See the example I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jody Klymak I was able to solve this. I added a few lines of code before saving the chart:

```py
plt.xticks()
locator = mpd.AutoDateLocator(interval_multiples=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
```

`matplotlib` changed the some default kwargs for Python 3, so the last 2 lines of code just change it back to it's old behavior. And `plt.xticks()` ensures that the dates are formatted correctly.